Customizing the 1d-CNN code in python for my problem
I want to train a 1d-CNN for my train data which includes 1443 samples and 24 features. The data samples are belong to 12 classes and the problem is a classification problem. Can you please help me to solve the issue and customize the network for my data with appropriate hyperparameters?
In order to do classification using 1d-CNN the following typical code is used and unfortunately it result in an error as below.
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn import svm
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Conv1D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling1D
verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 32
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = xrustrain.shape[0], xrustrain.shape[1],  yrustrain.values.ravel().shape[0]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(xrustrain, yrustrain.values.ravel(), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

##error
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b3a77a80e9d2> in <cell line: 324>()
    322 model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
    323 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
--> 324 model.fit(xrustrain, yrustrain.values.ravel(), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    325 yrus1 = model.predict(xrval)
    326 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1443, 24), found shape=(None, 24)


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please clarify the following. Your input is a sequence of 1443 samples/time steps, where each sample has 24 features. Each of the 1443 samples belongs to a class (1-12), and you want the model to predict the class for each sample? So if the input is shaped (1443 time steps, 24 features), you want an output prediction of (1443 time steps, n_classes)?

If so, there are issues with batching and the shape of the data in general...but please clarify the above points first so that I have a better idea of what you are aiming for.

Yes, that's right. The output for all samples will be a number from 0, 1, 2, ..., 11 (representative of 12 classes).

I really appreciate if you can help me to solve this problem.
